# Using commas in a CONCAT php mysql update

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have to perform a query similar to:

```
<?php
//....connect to database
$old = "a,b,c,d";
$new = "e,f,g,h";

$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT(" . $old . ", " . $new . ") WHERE something = 'something';
mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

So basically, I want to append the current database entry with the 'new' string which contains commas. But since the CONCAT function uses commas I'm having trouble.

Does anyone have any tips to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line

```
 $insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT(" . $old . ", " . $new . ") WHERE something = 'something'";
```

to this

```
$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT('$old', '$new') WHERE something = 'something'";
```

Edit:

And if you want a comma between the `$old` and `$new` strings you are concatenating, use CONCAT_WS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Like so:

```
 $insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT_WS(',', '$old', '$new') WHERE something = 'something'";
```

Comment: Do I not need to do the good 'ol:    " . $variable . " thing?
I can just do: CONCAT('$variable',$variable')? That's pretty useful!

Comment: @Learning you missed the quote *again*

Comment: Correct.  Since you are initializing your `$insert` variable with double quotes, it will perform variable expansion on any variables such as `$old` and `$new` and any single quotes will be interpreted literally as well.

Comment: I know haha...I was asking if in other examples without commas in my variables, is it unneccessary to break it up by using $variable = "function(" . $something . ")"; or like Kjones said simply do: $variable = "function($something)";
Although it probably depends on what function I'm using...

Comment: @Learning it depends on what *quotes* you are using. Learing the basic syntax of the language you are consumer of is quite a good idea. http://php.net/types.string

Answer (score 3):

Use the function mysql `CONCAT_WS()` -> Concatenate With Separator

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET FIELD_NAME = CONCAT_WS(",",FIELD_NAME,FIELD_NAME2) WHERE CONDITON
```

Answer (score 2):

strings in SQL queries has to be delimited by quotes.

```
$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT(FIELD,',','$new') WHERE ...";
```

there is also no point in breaking a PHP string, adding only useless noise.

Also, I smell a case for the [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes around the variables so that you get strings, like this (I also added a trailing double quote):

```
$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT('" . $old . "', '" . $new . "') WHERE something = 'something'";
```